# php request of a specific word but separable by spaces

Tags: php, regex

I have a question concerning regex, i.e. with the syntax that works with php.
I know some basics about regex in php, so I know that I can match something with

```
preg_match("/[maxmustermann ]/u", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Now I want to match all text which contains optional several words which by could be seperated by an space.

Sorry I just dont know how to ask. I try to make an example. I have this text and want to match all the bold ones.

> orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur **max** adipiscing elit. Proin **maxm** pellentesque dui **maxmustermann** eu erat **mustermann** rhoncus tempor sit amet quis odio. **Max Mustermann** habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. **Max Muster Mann** et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam vitae nisl dui.

That means I have this two words: **max** and **mustermann** and I want to match words (one ore more) which containing the letters of **max** and/or **mustermann** in the order how they are but also random placed space.

Thank you

Comment: How is `max` matching `maxm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with regex only. You need first to extract all words composed with your selected letters, and in a second time you have to filter these words. Something like this:

```
$word = 'maxmustermann';
preg_match_all('~\b[aemnrstux]+\b~ui', $txt, $matches);

$result = array_filter($matches[0], function ($i) use ($word) {
    return stripos($word, $i) !== false;
});
```

[demo](https://eval.in/777981)

You can proceed a similar way if you want to perform a replacement:

```
$word = 'maxmustermann';
$result = preg_replace_callback('~\b[aemnrstux]+\b~ui', function ($m) use ($word) {
    return stripos($word, $m[0]) !== false ? "#{$m[0]}#" : $m[0];
}, $txt);
```

[demo](https://eval.in/777983)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit update:**

After re-reading the question, this is a revised answer.
Just do a preg_match_all using the regex below.

OP criteria:

> I want to match all text which contains optional several words which by could be seperated by
>    an space. ...
>
> I want to match words (one ore more) which containing the letters of max and/or mustermann in
>    the order how they are but also random placed space.

For this you need to use whitespace boundary's.
All the item substrings are kept ordered by a alternative word boundary.

This regex will also match a group of substrings separated by whitespace.

`(?i)(?<!\S)(?!\s)(?:m|\b)(?:a|\b)(?:x|\b)(?:m|\b)(?:u|\b)(?:s|\b)(?:t|\b)(?:e|\b)(?:r|\b)(?:m|\b)(?:a|\b)(?:n|\b)(?:n|\b)(?:\s+(?!\s)(?:m|\b)(?:a|\b)(?:x|\b)(?:m|\b)(?:u|\b)(?:s|\b)(?:t|\b)(?:e|\b)(?:r|\b)(?:m|\b)(?:a|\b)(?:n|\b)(?:n|\b))*(?!\S)`

[101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/aMuXNb/2)

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   (?i)(?<!\S)(?!\s)(?:m|\b)(?:a|\b)(?:x|\b)(?:m|\b)(?:u|\b)(?:s|\b)(?:t|\b)(?:e|\b)(?:r|\b)(?:m|\b)(?:a|\b)(?:n|\b)(?:n|\b)(?:\s+(?!\s)(?:m|\b)(?:a|\b)(?:x|\b)(?:m|\b)(?:u|\b)(?:s|\b)(?:t|\b)(?:e|\b)(?:r|\b)(?:m|\b)(?:a|\b)(?:n|\b)(?:n|\b))*(?!\S)
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   6
Elapsed Time:    10.42 s,   10421.84 ms,   10421843 µs
```

Explained

```
 (?i)                  # Case insensitive modifier
 (?<! \S )             # Whitespace boundary behind
 (?! \s )              # Insure one of the next substrings match

 (?: m | \b )
 (?: a | \b )
 (?: x | \b )
 (?: m | \b )
 (?: u | \b )
 (?: s | \b )
 (?: t | \b )
 (?: e | \b )
 (?: r | \b )
 (?: m | \b )
 (?: a | \b )
 (?: n | \b )
 (?: n | \b )

 (?:
      \s+                   # Optional space and more words
      (?! \s )              # Insure one of the next substrings match
      (?: m | \b )
      (?: a | \b )
      (?: x | \b )
      (?: m | \b )
      (?: u | \b )
      (?: s | \b )
      (?: t | \b )
      (?: e | \b )
      (?: r | \b )
      (?: m | \b )
      (?: a | \b )
      (?: n | \b )
      (?: n | \b )
 )*
 (?! \S )              # Whitespace boundary ahead
```

Comment: Thank you for this sytanx explanation but it does not catch the *maxm* word.

Comment: @AllanKarlson - Added a pure regex solution. This is probably the faster way to do it (although the task is inherently slow no matter how it's done).

Answer (score 0):

You want a case-insensitive match using this regex:

```
/(max)|(muster)|(mann)/i
```

[EXAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/nia1SV/2)

EDIT: Thanks to @AbraCadaver for pointing out you'll also need `preg_match_all()`

Comment: You'll also need `preg_match_all`.